# Nested relations with Laravel 5.4 Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I'm new to both Laravel and Eloquent. I've built some straight forward projects which is just fine.

Now I'm attempting to build a more complex platform and I'm really getting stuck on relations.

Maybe the approach is wrong, if thats the case I would of course like to hear. The idea is as follows:

I would like to have products, which can be linked to multiple channels. Each product-channel combination requires a different account. 
Each product is linked to a main category, and for each category-channel combination it requires different parameters.

I've made the following tables:

```
channels
    id
    channel_name

accounts
    id
    user_id
    channel_id
    account_name

categories
    id
    category_name

products
    id
    user_id
    category_id
    product_name

channel_product
    channel_id
    product_id
    account_id
    pivot_data

category_channel
    channel_id
    category_id
```

At the moment I have the following models:

```
class Channel extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot(['pivot_data','account_id']);
    }
}

class Product extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function account()
    {
        return ????;
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function channel()
    {
        return ????;
    }
}
```

And the following code:

```
// Get channel
$channel = Channel::find(1);

// Get products for channel
$products = $channel->products;

// Walk through products
foreach ( $products as $product )
{
    // OK
    echo $product->product_name; 
    echo $product->user->user_name; 
    echo $product->category->category_name;
    echo $product->pivot->pivot_data;

    // NOT OK
    echo $product->account; // NOT OK
    echo $product->category->channel; // NOT OK
}
```

I cannot believe I'm trying to reach the impossible.

Of course I could do:
    $account = Account::get($product->pivot->account_id);

But I don't think thats the best solution. Hope any of you have got some insights!

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for most likely is this:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    // ...

    public function account()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Account::class, Channel::class);
    }
}

class Category extends Model
{
    public function channel()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Channel::class);
    }
}
```

For more insight, see:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: When adding the account relation to the Product model as you described, I end up with: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'channels.product_id' in 'field list' (SQL: select `accounts`.*, `channels`.`product_id` from `accounts` inner join `channe  
  ls` on `channels`.`id` = `accounts`.`channel_id` where `channels`.`product_id` = 1). This is when calling it like: $product->account